# Where is the "Core Data Starting Point" Apple Developer Doc?

Tags: core-data

In Apple's [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html), they have the following note:

> Important: Although this document provides a thorough treatment of the fundamentals of the Core Data framework, simply reading from start to finish is not a good strategy for learning how to use the technology effectively. Instead, you should typically augment your understanding by following the related tutorials provided in the Reference Library. For a description of the recommended learning path, see Core Data Starting Point.

If you scroll to the bottom of the page, the "See Also" section lists "Core Data Starting Point", but there's no link to the document.  Where is the document available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [Rob Bajorek's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455658/where-is-the-core-data-starting-point-apple-developer-doc/27500198#comment39721555_25455658),

> It's a "retired" document. Here you go: [Core Data Starting Point](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GettingStartedWithCoreData/index.html)

As for why it's retired, from the same page:

> Important
>
> This document may not represent best practices for current development. Links to downloads and other resources may no longer be valid.